# Problem with nullspace of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $$Ax=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Has one solution why the nullspace contains only the 0 vector?

My try was since $Ax$ has one solution then has linearly independent columns and doesn't have free variables

Comment: That seems like fine reasoning. There is a more direct method if you consider the contrapositive. If the nullspace of $A$ contains a non-zero vector $p$, then what is $A(x + p)$?

Comment: @TheoBendit This seems like a weird problem to me. Just because one vector in the range has one solution, that doesn’t mean that the matrix is injective.

Comment: @Seeker Well, as is the point of the exercise, it actually does mean this. I would suggest thinking about how you might construct a counterexample.

Comment: A(x+p) has no solution?

Comment: @RichardEissenhower $A(x + p)$ is not an equation, but an expression to evaluate. The term "solution" doesn't apply.  You assume that $x$ satisfies $Ax = (1, 0, 1)^\top$ and you assume $p \neq 0$ satisfies $Ap = (0, 0, 0)^\top$. How would you compute $A(x + p)$? Hint: matrix multiplication distributes over addition.

Comment: @RichardEissenhower Sorry, $(1, 0, 1)^\top$ should be $(0, 1, 0)^\top$.

Comment: Ax + Ap? could you post and answer explaining the full logic and where A(x+p)came from please

Comment: @RichardEissenhower Yes, $Ax + Ap$. Since $Ax = (0, 1, 0)^\top$ and $Ap = (0, 0, 0)^\top$, this means $A(x + p) = (0, 1, 0)^\top$. That makes $x + p$ a solution to the given equation. It's not the same solution, because $p \neq 0$.